# What is difference between ELOQUENT and QUERY-BUILDER in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i did some performance tests, The DB facade was much faster than Eloquent for many SQL statements etc,SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT.

So someone use the slower Laravel Eloquent rather than the faster DB facade, why?

for my new interview

Comment: Eloquent **models** implement the [active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). The **eloquent query builder**  is an extension to the query builder for which all data retrieval queries result in eloquent models (rather than plain objects which the regular query builder returns). It also includes additional methods to deal with relationships

Answer (score -1):

Eloquent is a powerful ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) tool in Laravel that allows you to work with your database using an intuitive and easy-to-use syntax. It can automatically handle the relationships of your models for you, making it easy to retrieve related models without writing complex queries. Eloquent provides a wide range of extra features, such as readability, accessors, mutators, JSON/Array conversion, hiding sensitive attributes, automatic timestamps, automatic attribute casting, soft deletes, and more. Eloquent is designed to make working with your database effortlessly and intuitive, even for developers with little or no database knowledge.
Find more about Eloquent [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent).

In contrast, the Query Builder is a simpler, more lightweight tool that allows you to build SQL queries using a fluent, chainable syntax. While it doesn't provide the same level of abstraction and convenience as Eloquent, it can be a great choice for more complex queries where you need precise control over the SQL being generated.

Find more about Query Builder [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#introduction)

Also, do some CRUDs using both of those. You will eventually understand when to use which one and why.

**N.B: In future do some research on your own before asking a new question here**